# Accessing Global Address Lists for multiple Outlook accounts

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, mapi

Trying my luck here after hour of searching.

Let's say you have Outlook 2010 with two active accounts: john.doe@company.com, admin.test@company.com.

You need to pull Global Address List for admin.test@company.com:

```cs
            using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

            Application app = new Application();
            NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            ns.Logon("", "", false, true);

            AddressList GAL = ns.AddressLists["Global Address List"];

            foreach (AddressEntry oEntry in GAL.AddressEntries)
            {
                // do something
            }
```

The problem here is that GAL can belong to either account and it's not obvious, at least by reading MSDN, how you suppose to specify which account you really want to use.

If we will go through all lists like that:

```cs
foreach (AddressList lst in ns.AddressLists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", lst.Name, lst.Index);
}
```

We can see that there is two entries named "Global Address List", two entries named "Contacts", etc with different indexes, but it's still not clear which one belongs to which account.

For folders it's done quite nicely since you can use constructs like that:

```cs
ns.Folders["admin.test@company.com"].Folders["Inbox"];
```

but I can't figure out similar mechanism for AddressLists.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this example help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184631.aspx

Comment: It could help if I can get a store from entry in ns.Accounts, so I can use it to match with PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID on AddressList. Account can have multiple stores, isn't?

Comment: There was also answer from Dmitry about using C++/Delphi, he already deleted it, but I would like to understand how to do it on C# .NET, if possible.

Comment: OK, I undeleted my answer - I did not want it to look like a plug for Redemption since Richard posted a sample (which I was not aware of) that does the same thing using OOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Account.CurrentUser UID and matched AddressList UID to select the correct list.
I don't know if using Store is a better approach, but this one works nicely.

Richard and Dmitry thank you for help.

Also Dmitry I want to thank you for maintaining the only source of all MAPI tags available on the Internet.

Code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

const string PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3D150102";

Application app = new Application();
NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
ns.Logon("", "", false, true);

string accountName = "admin.test@company.com";
string accountUID = null;

// Get UID for specified account name
foreach (Account acc in ns.Accounts)
{
    if (String.Compare(acc.DisplayName, accountName, true) == 0)
    {
        PropertyAccessor oPAUser = acc.CurrentUser.PropertyAccessor;
        accountUID = oPAUser.BinaryToString(oPAUser.GetProperty(PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID));
        break;
    }
}

// Select GAL with matched UID
foreach (AddressList GAL in ns.AddressLists)
{
    if (GAL.Name == "Global Address List")
    {
        PropertyAccessor oPAAddrList = GAL.PropertyAccessor;
        if (accountUID == oPAAddrList.BinaryToString(oPAAddrList.GetProperty(PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID)))
        {
            foreach (AddressEntry oEntry in GAL.AddressEntries)
            {
                // do something
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```